# Working with Email::MIME and byte strings

Tags: arrays, perl, email, mime-types

I'm a perl novice and trying to process the lines of an email using Email::MIME. I've managed to isolate the individual parts of the message, but the body parts appear to be available as "byte strings", which appear to be just one big string, and not a series of lines.

```
 my $parser = MIME::Parser->new;
 $parser->extract_uuencode(1);
 $parser->extract_nested_messages(1);
 $parser->output_to_core(0);
 my $buf;
 while(<STDIN> ){
         $buf .= $_;
 }
 my $entity = $parser->parse_data($buf);
 my @mailData;
 my $msg = Email::MIME->new($buf);
 foreach my $part ( $msg->subparts ) {
    foreach my $sub_part ($part->subparts) {
        print $sub_part->body;
   }
}
```

How can I write the $sub_part->body into an array such that I can process it line-by-line outside of those foreach() loops? I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
foreach my $line (@mailData) {
     print $line;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be line by line? You can just split it at newline. Your data from the other question was text anyway.